# Setting textbox value server-side then client-side then server-side

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have a textbox which I initialize on the razor form

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CheckSum"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CheckSum")%>' ClientIDMode="Predictable" />
```

On the client side this is rendered

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageGridView$ImagesGridView$ctl21$CheckSum" type="text" value="calculated Number A" id="CheckSum_19" >
```

On the client side I try to set the value

```
var checkSum = workingRow.querySelector("input[id^='CheckSum']");
// checkSum.value does not seem to change the value but add a new prop called value
checkSum.innerHTML = "calculated Number B";
```

That results in

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageGridView$ImagesGridView$ctl21$CheckSum" type="text" value="calculated Number A" id="CheckSum_19" >calculated Number B</input>
```

But when I return to the server and run

```
((TextBox)viewRow.FindControl("CheckSum")).Text
```

This still equals calculated Number A and not the updated value

What is the correct way to set a text box client-side and server-side

Comment: Does the `.Text` access the innerHTML or the value of the input? Have you tried setting value instead?

Comment: `.Text` accesses the value attribute `.Value` does not seem to exist on FindControl

Comment: If it accesses the value attribute, then you probably want to do `checkSum.value= "calculated Number B";` instead of `checkSum.innerHTML = "calculated Number B";`.

Comment: Correct but that doesn't actually change the attribute -- it actually just creates a new property and that is the problem

Comment: How does it create a new property, if it already has `value="calculated Number A"`? Does it have two value properties then? Wouldn't have thought, that it is possible for one HTML element to have more than one property with the same name.